# which are the commands for delete ciphers?

Tags: apache, ssl, configuration

I have some vulnerabilities with ciphers. Anonymous chipers, ssl rc4 cipher suites supported, ssl medium strength cipher.

And i am trying to fix it with

```
openssl ciphers -v ‘!aNULL:!eNULL’ 
openssl ciphers -v ‘ALL:!LOW’
```

and others commands but when I reload the nessusd scan, I still have the vulnerabilities.

Someone can help me please.

Comment: This *might* be considered off-topic for Stackoverflow, and be more appropriate for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).  While building a custom and limited OpenSSL would solve your problem, and in that case it would belong here as involves customizing software, it's really a whole lot easier to just configure Apache to be secure, assuming you're running reasonably up-to-date versions of OpenSSL and Apache.  And just configuring your web server is more appropriate for those other sites.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @vcsjones answer, you do **not** want to rebuild OpenSSL. You do not want to become dependent upon keeping an up-to-date, custom OpenSSL build.

You simply need to configure your Apache install to use the proper ciphers.

And the easiest way to do that is to use the [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) to generate the proper options for the versions of web server and SSL provider you're using.

Comment: @vcsjones Thanks.  I felt that the questioner got wrapped up in fixing OpenSSL without realizing that just configuring Apache would be a lot easier. I've dealt with Nessus output myself many times, and it's not really easy for non-experts in whatever is being scanned to determine the easiest way to fix the vulnerabilities it finds.

Answer (score 1):

You can only remove ciphers from OpenSSL by recompiling it without the ciphers you want. The command you entered above just simply lists ciphers that meet the criteria you entered.

The correct solution however is to configure the software that is *using* OpenSSL to not use those ciphers from OpenSSL. For example, with nginx you might do something like this:

```
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
```

It depends on the software you are trying to configure. There is ample documentation on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, etc. on how to configure nginx, Apache, etc.

Comment: i use apache. but i want to reconfigure openssl for use high stregnth ciphers, remove anonymous. which is the command for delete ciphers. i tryied with your command but doesn't works

Comment: @RafaelHernández *but i want to reconfigure openssl* No, you don't want to configure OpenSSL, you just want to configure how Apache *uses* OpenSSL.  Creating a custom OpenSSL build that will work properly is a lot harder than simply configuring Apache to be secure.

Comment: i put the cipher generate by mozilla SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-R.... in ssl.conf and restarted the apache but the vulnerabilities still exits